# Cannot resolve DataType MyApp.Model.Paper

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to bind a class to a template.

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyApp.Controls.PaperSelectControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <GridView x:Name="paperGrid" 
                      ItemsSource="{x:Bind Papers}"
                      Width="400" Height="300" >
                <GridView.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="MyApp.Model.Paper" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Color}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
            </GridView>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

the `MyApp.Model.Paper` is the class namespace.

```
namespace MyApp.Model {
    public class Paper {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public string Thumb { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But i always get the

> Cannot resolve DataType MyApp.Model.Paper

error

I hope someone can help me to resolve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: What does `x` point to in the header of your XAML file ?

Comment: I just added the complete header markup ! @user3185569

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I known we cannot set the `x:DataType` markup by `namespace.class`  format. For accessing your own custom types you can map a XAML namespace, this mapping is made by defining an `xmlns` prefix.  For example, `xmlns:myTypes` defines a new XAML namespace that is accessed by prefixing all usages with the token `myTypes:`.

So please add this mapping `xmlns:model="using:MyApp.Model"` to your header markup list. And updated the XAML code for `x:DataType` as follows:   `<DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Paper" >`, then build your project it will work.

More details please reference [Mapping custom types to XAML namespaces and prefixes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping#mapping-custom-types-to-xaml-namespaces-and-prefixes).